# What are the technical terms for inner narrative in neuroscience?

Tags: neuroscience

This is about neurological function and more along the lines of physical interaction in our brains.  Less so about psychology.

What do we call, in neuroscience, the "Inner Narrative"?  But I don't mean specifically the phenomenon where we are talking to ourselves (the "inner monologue"), but more along the lines where the brain is constructing, from all of our sensory input, the full and coherent story of what is happening in our immediate presence at the present time.

So the notion of an *"elephant in the room"* taken a little more figuratively is that as we move about and do things, we are expecting certain reactions and consequences from our environment that we expect to perceive with our senses, but when something **significant** is perceived differently from what we expect, from our inner narrative, then this reality is compared, perhaps in the cerebellum, to the story we *had* been constructing right up to the present, and then that difference is processed and acted on.

Sorta like when we're driving on an uneventful multilane highway and some jerk suddenly pulls into our lane directly in front of us, causing us to react quickly.  Or, for humans 20,000 years ago, when we're foraging and suddenly hear the growl from the saber-tooth tiger, we might react in a manner that might save one's life.

Or here's a humorous example:
[image]

What is that part of our brain that is creating the narrative of our present moment (in juxtaposition with past moments and expected future moments), a story that makes sense from our recent physical senses.  And then what is the part of the brain comparing that narrative of the present to the actual sensed reality at present and, based on the difference, reacting?

Someone else can add tags to this.  I dunno which are the correct ones to add.

Comment: Closing question as it doesn't show evidence of prior research, use of language appropriate for the field, or provide references for premises it's based on. I'm struggling to understand what is being asked, but maybe you are interested in [predictive coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_coding)?

Comment: The funny thing is that I'm an electrical engineer and a signal processing person and we have ***our*** version of [predictive coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding).  I didn't know about this, nor would have ever guessed it.  As for evidence of prior research, I have never claimed that I knew diddley about neurophysiology.  I wouldn't know where to begin, but I learned that there a "brain comparator", but it was for simpler physical movement like reaching, not for more complex stories. It looks like your recommendation is a good place for me to begin.